# jquery - disable all inputs in form with :not(these)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Not sure if this is possible or I'm just not writing it properly :

```
}).on("change", function (e) {
    $("#searchForm:not('#locationName') :input").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

`#searchForm` is the id of the entire form

`#locationName` is the id of a particular input I would like to exclude (there is more than just this one, but this is an example)

I have more than a few input ID's I would like to exclude and a large list of them in the form so I would prefer not to disable each one by one... I want to use the not() selector if possible.

I've tried a few different ways to write this and can't seem to get it working.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] please?

Comment: Do you really need more than this? There isn't much to it if you look... `$("#searchForm :input").prop("disabled", true);` will disable all inputs in the form.  I need to exclude specific input ID's from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code looks for inputs in a `#searchForm` element that is also not a `#locationName` element. Since an element can have only one ID, it doesn't make sense. You're applying the `:not` to the wrong element.

You meant to put the `:not` on the `:input` pseudo-class.

```
$("#searchForm :input:not(#locationName)").prop("disabled", true);
```

Also note you don't need quotes around the seletor in `:not`.

If you have multiple elements to exclude, remember that when you build a compound selector, it's ANDed together, so use multiple `:not`s:

```
$("#searchForm :input:not(#locationName):not(#somethingElse)").prop("disabled", true);
```

Actually, having said, that, I see from [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) that they extend `:not` to allow group selectors:

```
// Only valid with jQuery
$("#searchForm :input:not(#locationName, #somethingElse)").prop("disabled", true);
```

That's [not valid in CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) which only allows [simple selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) there, it's a jQuery extension (like `:input` is). By using jQuery extensions, you force jQuery to handle the selector itself with its Sizzle engine rather than handing off to the browsers dramatically-more-efficient built-in engine, but in most cases the difference in speed doesn't matter.

Alternately, you could use the [`.not` *function*](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
// Only valid with jQuery
$("#searchForm :input").not("#locationName, #somethingElse").prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Yes, that is it.  Thank you.  The ANDed would've been my next question as I would be trying to use comma separated as you do with selectors.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @user756659: Actually, jQuery extends `:not` to allow you to use a group selector: `:not(#locationName, #somethingElse)`. But that's a jQuery extension (like `:input` is). CSS's `:not` doesn't allow it. I've updated the answer to clarify that.

Comment: Thanks.  I need to add to this, but you can also do this `$("#searchForm :input:not(#locationName, #locationSubmit):not(#locationOptions :input)").prop("disabled", true);`.  So for example, I have a group of radio options in #locationOptions I can exclude the entire group rather than list each individually. Or `$("#searchForm :input:not(#locationName, #locationSubmit, #locationOptions :input)").prop("disabled", true);`

Comment: As an extension, you'd be better off adding a class to the ones you don't want to validate `$("#searchForm :input:not(.skipvalidation)").prop(..` then you don't need to change your code when you update the form (eg add new controls).

Comment: @freedomn-m: Big time. How did I not include that?!

Answer (score 3):

> `#searchForm` is the id of the entire form
>
> `#locationName` is the id of a particular input I would like to exclude

In this case the `:not` should be on the `:input`, not the `#searchForm`:

```
.on("change", function (e) {
  $("#searchForm :input:not('#locationName')").prop("disabled", true);
});
```